# How to filter a dictionary using regex on value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to filter a dictionary in ansible based on regex matching it's values.

```
mydict:
  some_value: /my/path
  another_value: 2345
  anotherpath: /my/other/path
```

What I tried is:

```
set_fact:
  newvar: "{{ mydict | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'match', '^/my/.+$') | list }}"
```

But what i get is:

`expected string or buffer`

How can I filter all values based on part of their string for using them  later in with_items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you currently have is that the regex `match` cannot handle integers. This will solve your issue, though it's slightly more verbose:

```
  - set_fact:
      file_list: []

  - set_fact:
      file_list: "{{ file_list + [item.value] }}"
    when: item.value|string | match('^/my/.+$')
    loop: "{{ mydict | dict2items }}"
```

If you can ensure that all values will always be strings, then you could use:

```
  - set_fact:
      newvar: "{{ mydict | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'match', '^/my/.+$') | map(attribute='value') | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @matt-p for clarifying :-) I didn't know this was actually caused by the match function itself. Is this more like an issue I should report to the Ansible community?

BTW I changed your code a little bit to fit the actual Ansible standard (the when condition is using deprecated syntax):

```
- set_fact:
    file_list: []

- set_fact:
    file_list: "{{ file_list + [item.value] }}"
  when:
    - item.value is string 
    - item.value is match('^/my/.+$')
  with_items: "{{ mydict | dict2items }}"
```